# How to Change the title of done button of ytplayer in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, ytplayer

[image]

I'm beginner so I'm working on video app and using `YTPlayer` for playing YouTube videos in `Objective-C`.

project is working good but there is little thing about done button its shows `PLAYBACK_CONTROLS_VIEW_CONTROllER_DONE` instead `DONE`.

Comment: can you add some screen shot

Comment: sorry i'm new in stackoverflow and i required 10 point to share screenshot...so they don't allow me to post...

Comment: now you can add

Comment: actually i have tried to hide navigation bar but this doesn't happen...i don't know from where the view is appearing.there is no such file in xibi or storyboard.. how can i hide or change this done button...
i'm just using ..

Comment: - (void)enteredFullScreen:(NSNotification *) notification {

    
}


- (void)exitedFullScreen:(NSNotification *) notification {
    
    ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).videoIsInFullscreen = NO;
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    
}